# Libgdx assets game design

Tags: libgdx, assets

I want to make a game with libgdx support 800 x 480 and 1280 x 720 screen. what size assets graphic design for game? is background image size  800 x 480 or 1280 x 720 ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  Viewports to deal with different screens  and different aspect ratios.
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

If you need to reduce the file size of your png assets, you can use PngQuant : 
http://pngquant.org

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my game I'm making all the graphics to support full hd - 1920x1080. And then I'm setting calculated camera zoom to display whole visible area to specific device resolution.

Comment: could you tell me how it works on old devices which `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` not support ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want blurry assets use the larger one. If you want the smallest package and don't care for blurry assets use the smaller one. I'd always go for the larger one unless you won't see the difference or if there are memory issues.